# Email Delivery Issue from Subdomain while using SendGrid Email Api

Tags: c#

I am facing Email Delivery Issue from Subdomain. I am using same code on main domain and sub-domain. The Email deliver fine when I test with Main domain, but the mail will not deliver if I use the sub-domain URL. Both main and sub-domains already authenticated.

I got the response status is "WaitingForActivation"

Comment: Finally, I have found a solution; after a lot of search, I found that I had to add this line of code in the Application_Start() function in global.asax.cs file.

System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true; System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;